# Review Edited Layers Before Saving

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing

In Arcmap, is there a plugin/addon available that will list the layers that have been edited when the "Save Edits" dialog pops up? Sometimes I get nervous that I might have deleted something from a layer that I didn't intend to edit. If so, I don't want to save my edits. Before clicking 'Save Edits', it would be helpful to review a list of layers that were edited.

I know I can toggle layer selectability, however, I have made mistakes in the past and I thought this would be an extra layer of defense against mistakes.

Comment: Never heard or seen. All of the actions performed on a layer while editing can be saved when catching the events fired by the editing operations. This might be a good case for using the ArcObjects - http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Edit_event_listener/000100000443000000/. If this is an option for you - consider move your feature class into a new geodatabase for editing purposes - you can have only one geodatabase open for editing at the same time which means you won't be able to edit any other feature class apart from the one in the active gdb

Comment: Moving into a new gdb would accomplish the same as toggling selectability, which is a point that I noted in the post. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I recommend use "Editor Tracking" choose your feature class in Geo-database and then right click on feature class finally select "Enable Editor Tracking..."

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ArcSDE, you can set up versioning:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/a-quick-tour-of-registering-and-unregistering-data-as-versioned.htm

You can then review changes using the Version Changes tool:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/the-version-changes-command.htm